# Como montar este SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho essas tabelas:

Cliente:

```
cliente
------- 
id nome 
id_municipio
```

Municipio:

```
municipio
-------
id
nome
```

Regional:

```
regional
-------
id
nome
```

Regional_municipio:

```
regional_municipio
-------
id_municipio
id_regional
```

Na tabela `regional_municipio` eu coloco por exemplo, municipio 17 se refere à regional 1

Eu preciso fazer um `select` que dê um `count` de cliente por regional.

Por exemplo:

- regional 1 tem 500 clientes
- regional 2 tem 50 clientes
- regional 3 tem 100 clientes

Sendo que na tabela cliente eu só tenho o número do município, como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTDE, C.NOME FROM CLIENTE A LEFT JOIN  REGIONAL_MUNICIPIO B 
LEFT JOIN REGIONAL C ON C.ID = B.ID_REGIONAL
ON A.ID_MUNICIPIO = B.ID_MUNICIPIO
GROUP BY C.NOME
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem o `id_municipio` para identificar o município do cliente, basta fazer uma ligação com a tabela `regional_municipio` e efetuar o count! Creio que esse SQL resolva seu problema.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN regional_municipio rm
ON rm.id_municipio = c.id_municipio
WHERE rm.id_regional = /*ID_REGIONAL*/
```